# How to separate boolean column values on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
create table votes(
    candidate varchar(20),
    voteup bool
)
```

and I want to display something like this

```
|candidate|vote ups(true)|vote downs(false)|vote points(true-false)
|hitler   |16            |104              |-88
|obama    |119           |1                |118
```

Comment: use case to match condition

Comment: sorry im new to sql. what is a case match?

Comment: Sounds like you want a pivot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table.

Comment: @user1625766: uhh, use Google?

Comment: BOOL and BOOLEAN in MySQL are synonyms for TINYINT(1) so you'd be dealing with a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "abuse" the fact that boolean values evaluate as 1 and 0 in integer operations:

```
select candidate,
    sum(voteup) as 'vote up',
    sum(voteup=0) as 'vote down',
    sum(if(voteup,1,-1)) as 'vote points'
from votes
group by candidate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT candidate, 
       SUM(IF(voteup=0,0,1)) 'vote ups (true)',
       SUM(IF(voteup=0,1,0)) 'vote downs (false)',
       SUM(IF(voteup,1,-1)) 'vote points (true-false)'
FROM votes
GROUP BY candidate
```

I changed my original answer because BOOL / TINYINT(1) can contain any number between -128 and 127